# Real Time Face Recognition with LBP, Deep Learning and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision, face-recognition

I am a novice in Computer Vision. I am trying to implement Real Time Face Recognition with Local Binary Patterns with its Face Detection part based on Deep Learning dnn module. I am using the caltech_faces dataset and have added a folder with my 20 photos to it.

So, this is my code. I basically transformed the code of the Face Recognition of sample images to a Real Time Face Recognition by making some changes and additions.

I get the following error when executing the below code:

```
predName = le.inverse_transform([predictions[i]])[0]
                                                       ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

I checked all the tabs and indentations, and cant find what and where to fix. I kindly ask you to give me a hint on what to do. Thank you very much!

```
# import the necessary packages

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from imutils import paths
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import cv2
import os


#Creating our face detector

def detect_faces(net, frame, minConfidence=0.5):
    # grab the dimensions of the image and then construct a blob
    # from it
    (h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1.0, (300, 300),
        (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))

    # pass the blob through the network to obtain the face detections,
    # then initialize a list to store the predicted bounding boxes
    net.setInput(blob)
    detections = net.forward()
    boxes = []

    # loop over the detections
    for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):
        # extract the confidence (i.e., probability) associated with
        # the detection
        confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]

        # filter out weak detections by ensuring the confidence is
        # greater than the minimum confidence
        if confidence > minConfidence:
            # compute the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding box for
            # the object
            box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
            (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")

            # update our bounding box results list
            boxes.append((startX, startY, endX, endY))

    # return the face detection bounding boxes
    return boxes


#Loading the CALTECH Faces dataset

def load_face_dataset(inputPath, net, minConfidence=0.5,
    minSamples=15):
    # grab the paths to all images in our input directory, extract
    # the name of the person (i.e., class label) from the directory
    # structure, and count the number of example images we have per
    # face
    imagePaths = list(paths.list_images(inputPath))
    names = [p.split(os.path.sep)[-2] for p in imagePaths]
    (names, counts) = np.unique(names, return_counts=True)
    names = names.tolist()

    # initialize lists to store our extracted faces and associated
    # labels
    faces = []
    labels = []

    # loop over the image paths
    for imagePath in imagePaths:
        # load the image from disk and extract the name of the person
        # from the subdirectory structure
        frame = cv2.imread(imagePath)
        name = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]

        # only process images that have a sufficient number of
        # examples belonging to the class
        if counts[names.index(name)] < minSamples:
            continue

        # perform face detection
        boxes = detect_faces(net, frame, minConfidence)

        # loop over the bounding boxes
        for (startX, startY, endX, endY) in boxes:
            # extract the face ROI, resize it, and convert it to
            # grayscale
            faceROI = frame[startY:endY, startX:endX]
            faceROI = cv2.resize(faceROI, (47, 62))
            faceROI = cv2.cvtColor(faceROI, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

            # update our faces and labels lists
            faces.append(faceROI)
            labels.append(name)

    # convert our faces and labels lists to NumPy arrays
    faces = np.array(faces)
    labels = np.array(labels)

    # return a 2-tuple of the faces and labels
    return (faces, labels)

#Implementing Local Binary Patterns for face recognition    

# # construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
# ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# ap.add_argument("-i", "--input", type=str, required=True,
#   help="path to input directory of images")
# ap.add_argument("-f", "--face", type=str,
#   default="face_detector",
#   help="path to face detector model directory")
# ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.5,
#   help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
# args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# since we are using Jupyter Notebooks we can replace our argument
# parsing code with *hard coded* arguments and values
args = {
    "input": "caltech_faces",
    "face": "face_detector",
    "confidence": 0.5,
}

# load our serialized face detector model from disk
print("[INFO] loading face detector model...")
prototxtPath = os.path.sep.join([args["face"], "deploy.prototxt"])
weightsPath = os.path.sep.join([args["face"],
    "res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"])
net = cv2.dnn.readNet(prototxtPath, weightsPath)

# load the CALTECH faces dataset
print("[INFO] loading dataset...")
(faces, labels) = load_face_dataset(args["input"], net,
    minConfidence=0.5, minSamples=20)
print("[INFO] {} images in dataset".format(len(faces)))

# encode the string labels as integers
le = LabelEncoder()
labels = le.fit_transform(labels)

# construct our training and testing split
(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(faces,
    labels, test_size=0.25, stratify=labels, random_state=42)

# train our LBP face recognizer
print("[INFO] training face recognizer...")
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create(
    radius=2, neighbors=16, grid_x=8, grid_y=8)
start = time.time()
recognizer.train(trainX, trainY)
end = time.time()
print("[INFO] training took {:.4f} seconds".format(end - start))


# initialize the list of predictions and confidence scores
print("[INFO] gathering predictions...")
predictions = []
confidence = []
start = time.time()

# loop over the test data
for i in range(0, len(testX)):
    # classify the face and update the list of predictions and
    # confidence scores
    (prediction, conf) = recognizer.predict(testX[i])
    predictions.append(prediction)
    confidence.append(conf)

# measure how long making predictions took
end = time.time()
print("[INFO] inference took {:.4f} seconds".format(end - start))

# show the classification report
print(classification_report(testY, predictions,
    target_names=le.classes_))


# initialize the video stream and allow the cammera sensor to warmup
print("[INFO] starting video stream...")
vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
time.sleep(2.0)

# loop over the frames from the video stream
while True:

    # grab the frame from the threaded video stream and resize it
    # to have a maximum width of 400 pixels
    face = vs.read()
    face = imutils.resize(face, width=400)

    # loop over the detections
    for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):

        # grab the predicted name and actual name
    predName = le.inverse_transform([predictions[i]])[0]
    actualName = le.classes_[testY[i]]


    # draw the predicted name and actual name on the image
    cv2.putText(face, "pred: {}".format(predName), (5, 25),
    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.putText(face, "actual: {}".format(actualName), (5, 60),
    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (0, 0, 255), 2)

    # display the predicted name, actual name, and confidence of the
    # prediction (i.e., chi-squared distance; the *lower* the distance
    # is the *more confident* the prediction is)
    print("[INFO] prediction: {}, actual: {}, confidence: {:.2f}".format(predName, actualName, confidence[i]))

# show the output frame
cv2.imshow("Face", face)
key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
 
# if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
if key == ord("q"):
    break
```

Comment: if you think you use wrong values then maybe read documentation to see what values it needs. And maybe there will bo some example. You could also use `print()` to see what you have in variables and you will see if you use correct values.

Comment: do you get error message? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: why do you think you use wrong values? Do you get wrong results? Show it in question (not in comment).  And show expected result.  We can't run code, we can't see your screen, we can't read in your mind - you have to describe all details in questions.

Comment: @furas, thank you for the feedback! I have updated my post as per your instructions. This is my first semester as a CENG student and my first time on the Stackoverflow. I now get it how to properly operate here! Thank you again for guiding!

Comment: check in editor/IDE if it has option `convert all tabs to 4 spaces` and this should resovle this problem. Some editors/IDEs have even option to convert tabs to spaces when you write file or when you press tab - and this also resolve this problem. And if editor doesn't have this optiosn then you can still use function `search & replace` to get all tabs and replace with 4 spaces. `tab` and `4 spaces` looks the same but `Python` doesn't like when you use both - you have to use one of them. In some editors/IDEs you can press tab and it will convert to 4 spaces.

Comment: line with `predName = ...` shows that there is wrong indentation - it needs more spaces to put it inside `for`-loop. The same is with `actualName = ...`

Comment: @furas I use Sublime and it has the 4 space option. I corrected the predName and actualName spaces inside the for loop, but still the same error. I think maybe it has to do something with the ([predictions[i]])[0] argument? Thank you!

Comment: `tabs and spaces in indentation` has nothing to do with variables - only with spaces/tabs at the beginning of lines. You still have problem with spaces/tabs. Do you get the same error fot the same line? Maybe delete all before this line and put spaces again. Problem can be also if you in this line use spaces but in previous use tabs. You have to use spaces in all lines. If you have function to convert tabs to 4 spaces then use it for all file, not only for this one line. Spaces has be also before comments.

Answer (score 0):

You have a **for** loop without any line of code but a comment just before the line that cause the problem:

```
# loop over the detections
for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):

    # grab the predicted name and actual name
predName = le.inverse_transform([predictions[i]])[0]
actualName = le.classes_[testY[i]]
```

The problem comes from this empty loop; if you have a loop, you must have at least one line of code inside. So delete it or add the **pass** keyword inside.

Answer (score 0):

I am using google collab for this and first of all, make sure you have OpenCV installed. You can install it using pip:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Before detecting the face we should have to open the web camera using google collab.

```
from IPython.display import display, Javascript
from google.colab.output import eval_js
from base64 import b64decode
def take_photo(filename='photo.jpg', quality=0.8):
js = Javascript('''
async function takePhoto(quality) {
const div = document.createElement('div');
const capture = document.createElement('button');
capture.textContent = 'Capture';
div.appendChild(capture);
const video = document.createElement('video');
video.style.display = 'block';
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});
document.body.appendChild(div);
div.appendChild(video);
video.srcObject = stream;
await video.play();
// Resize the output to fit the video element.     google.colab.output.setIframeHeight(document.documentElement.scrollHeight, true);
// Wait for Capture to be clicked.
await new Promise((resolve) => capture.onclick = resolve);
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0);
stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
div.remove();
return canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', quality);
}
''')
display(js)
data = eval_js('takePhoto({})'.format(quality))
binary = b64decode(data.split(',')[1])
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
f.write(binary)
return filename
```

You have to run the below code as the second step.

```
from IPython.display import Image
try:
filename = take_photo()
print('Saved to {}'.format(filename))
# Show the image which was just taken.
display(Image(filename))
except Exception as err:
# Errors will be thrown if the user does not have a webcam or if they do 
not
# grant the page permission to access it.
print(str(err))
```

After running these two codes, the web camera is opened and you can capture a photo.
The photo is saved as photo.jpg.

Face detection using Haar cascades is a machine learning-based approach where a cascade function is trained with a set of input data. OpenCV already contains many pre-trained classifiers for face, eyes, smiles, etc. Today we will be using the face classifier. You can experiment with other classifiers as well.